# Sending Email with Codeigniter Taking So much time

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Here is my code in which sending an email when user signup. It takes 5 minutes or more for every mail to reaches to the user email. I do not know why email taking so much time to reach. if I am sending an email with this same function **sendEmail()** not with a verification code only with a simple text. Now it takes 1 minute or 1 n half minutes to reach the user email.

**Sometimes it does not even send any email when I am sending the verification code at the end of the link.**

I do not know how to send the email with SMTP. I found some examples where they add their domain name to the smtp_host, email, password, which email is created with the domain. I did the same but nothing happens with my email sending. It almost same with this also whether I am using SMTP or not.

This is my function name **sendEmail(**) which I have created the model to sending emails. The reason why I have created this function in the model because I have to send emails from other controllers too.
I do not if it could be a problem in sending emails

Please see this function where I am doing wrong. or if there is another way please tell me how to do this.or any type of suggestions will be very helpful for me.

**Controller**

```
function index() {
        //my validation rules are here  
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

            $data = $this->fetch_data_from_post();
            $user_email = $data['email'];
            $code =  random_string('unique');
            $verification_link = base_url('Home/verify/').$code;
            $subject = "Confirmation Message";
            $message = "Dear User,\n\n\nPlease click on Given below URL  to verify your Email Address ".$verification_link." \n\n Once you click on the above link then your account will be verified and you will get an opportunity to login. See you soon,Thank You...!\n";
            $email_sent = $this->Perfect_mdl->sendEmail($user_email,$subject,$message);

            if($email_sent != 1){
                $flash = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Opppssss Somthing went Wrong...</div>';
                $this->session->set_flashdata('user_registration',$flash);
                redirect('Home/signup');

            }else{
                $this->Perfect_mdl->_insert($data);
                $flash = '<div class="alert alert-success">You are Successfully Registered... Please Check Your Email <b>'.$user_email.'</b> For Verification</div>';
                $this->session->set_flashdata('user_registration',$flash);
                redirect('Home/signup');
            }
        }

        $data['meta_title']  = "Signup";
        $data['services_name'] = $this->Perfect_mdl->getServices_home();
        $dat['flash'] = $this->session->flashdata('user_registration');
        $this->load->view('signup',$data);
    }
```

Model:-

```
function sendEmail($useremail,$subject,$message) {


     $config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'smtp.mydomainname.com',
    'smtp_port' => 25,
    'smtp_user' => 'vishal@mydomainname.com', // change it to yours
    'smtp_pass' => 'vishal123456', // change it to yours
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
    'crlf' => "\r\n",
    'newline' => "\r\n",
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );
    $this->load->library('email', $config); 
    $this->email->from('vishal@mydomainname.com', 'Company Name');
    $this->email->to($useremail);   


    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);
    if($this->email->send()){
        return "1";
    }else{
        return "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `SMTP` are you sending from a different server then the one the code is on?  If it's all on localhost, then there is no need for `SMTP`

Comment: I do not know how smtp work. the reason i am using smtp to sending as fast  as possible to reach  user emails. No i'm using this with server.

Comment: remove that smpt config array..in live host no need to use this smtp  config..

Comment: @Mahesh After removing this config. The condition is same . Why is took so long to reach

Comment: just write the email code in controller itself and check...it may work faster....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be the class that is slow, it will be the SMTP mail server you are trying to connect to that sends the email that is making the page lag.
here are some of my suggestions.

First of all, create a custom config file `email.php` inside `application/config`
Please make sure this config is autoloaded. Open your `Autoload.php` inside `application/config` and write `$autoload['config'] = array('email');`

In my case I am sending email via webmail id, so here is my `email.php`

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'SMTP_HOST_NAME',
    'smtp_port' => 25,
    'smtp_user' => 'SMTP_USER_NAME', // change it to your user name
    'smtp_pass' => 'SMTP_PASSWORD', // change it to your password
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
);
```

Use parent construct like this:

```
function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();          
  $this->load->library('email', $config);
}
```

And then you can emails easily just be like this:

```
$this->email->from('info@example.net', 'Account');
$this->email->to('johndoe@example.com');
$this->email->cc('johndoe@example.com');
$this->email->bcc('johndoe@example.com');
$this->email->subject('Account Confirmation');
$message = "any message body you want to send";
$this->email->message($message);
$this->email->send();
```

If you following this procedure then maybe it can save some seconds.

Comment: After adding this into my construct `$this->load->library('email', $config);
` Why this is throwing a error : Undefined $config, But i have already created a file name `email.php` into my config folder, And also added `$autoload['config'] = array('email');` into my `autoload.php`.

Comment: have you created as same as I do in my answer? @vishalkumar

Comment: once you initialize the email config in the constructor then you don't need to call `$config`  only if you are calling it in the controller. @vishalkumar

Comment: @vishalkumar if my suggested answer helps then you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

try like this in your controller....

```
public function sendResetEmail($params) {

        $params['body'] = 'emails/password_reset';
        $params['title'] = 'Forgot Password';
        $params['subject'] = 'Mail From Admin - Reset Password ';
        $params['reset_url'] = base_url() . 'login/reset/?key=' . $params['reset_key'] . '&email=' . $params['email_user'];
        $params['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
        $this->email->from('info@example.co.in', 'admin');
        $this->email->to($params['email_user']);
        $this->email->subject($params['subject']);
        $this->email->message($this->load->view('emails/main', $params, true)); 
        $this->email->send();
}
```

Comment: Sometime email reaches in 2 minutes. But if its not  reaches then it took five minutes. is it possible to send emails faster (less than a minutes).